# How to Reposition items inside Grouped list and Reposition Group in flutter?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, drag-and-drop, grouped-list

Need to Reposition item inside grouped list by drag and drop and also need to Reposition group by drag and drop in flutter

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looking for the [ReorderableListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html) widget.

I believe if you want to reorder items and groups, you could do this using a ReorderableListView as the ListItem for another ReorderableListView.

Comment: okay thanks! will try and share result